# Why do two objects share an attribute here?

Tags: python

Under very simple circumstances, two objects can unintentionally share an attribute such as a list. **Is there a reasoning behind this design choice of the language?**

I define a class `A` with a list attribute `children` set by `__init__` and empty by default. When I create two instances of `A`, they share the same empty list instead of two separate lists being created. Adding a child to one automatically adds it to the other as well.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, children=[]):
        self.children = children

a1, a2 = A(), A()

print(a1, a1.children, id(a1.children))
print(a2, a2.children, id(a2.children))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x1023d9f28> [] 4331130696
<__main__.A object at 0x1023f6080> [] 4331130696
```

Both objects have the *same* empty list as `children`, instead of two separate empty lists, which is what I would expect. This can be realized e. g. like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, children=None):
        if children is not None:
            self.children = children
        else:
            self.children = [] # creates a fresh new empty list each time
```

But having to write this boilerplate `if`-block defeats IMO the benefit of default argument values. **Why does Python behave in this way** and what is the most pythonic way to handle the situation?

Comment: `self.children = children or []` if `0`, `''` etc are not valid values for `self.children`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what stumped me, just in OOP form! The lesson I take home is to not use mutable objects as default values. They shouldn't be able to contain much state anyway, but rather be numbers, strings ar bools.